# asp.net Tab Control causes index out of bounds error on callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a simple application with a GridView bound to a LinqDataSource and a DetailView that displays a row from the GridView when it's selected. This works as expected. But now I'm placing the GridView and DetailView in separate TabPanels in an asp.net ajax Tab Control.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TabContainer ID="CourseFinder" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="ResultsTab" runat="server" HeaderText="Results" > 
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="DetailTab" runat="server" HeaderText="Detail">
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

and my code behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CourseFinder.Tabs[0].Controls.Add(Results);
    CourseFinder.Tabs[1].Controls.Add(DetailsView1);
}
```

When I run the page I'm getting

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than 
the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +7483656
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +13
_Default.Results_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Documents and   
Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 
2008\WebSites\WebSite1\Default.aspx.cs:35
...
```

The line of code getting the error is the one attempting to get the SelectedIndex from the GridView and update my DetailView.

```
 GridViewRow row = Results.Rows[Results.SelectedIndex];
```

I stepped through the code with the debugger and SelectedIndex is not negative and it's not larger than the number of rows in the GridView. So I'm confused why simply placing the controls inside a Tab is causing this error?

Comment: Are you adding the panels dynamically?

Comment: Yes but that's only because I was unable to find a way to do it otherwise. There aren't many good examples of how to use the tabs so I just define them in my page (Default.aspx) and then in the code behind on Page_load I'm adding the controls to each tab individually.

Comment: Is there another way to get the tabs to display without adding them dynamically? I couldn't get them to display otherwise

Comment: Don't do that. It makes things much more complicated. You could add your GridView/DetailsView to an userControl and add this to the ContentTemplate of the TabPanel. Here is a good tutorial on how to lazy-load TabPanels: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html

Comment: @Tim: That solved the problem! Thank you very much. If you would put that comment in an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Matt: added as answer. I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you adding the panels dynamically? [Karel]
>
> Yes...
>
> Is there another way to get the tabs
> to display without adding them
> dynamically? I couldn't get them to
> display otherwise [Matt Phillips]

Don't do that! It makes things much more complicated.
You could add your GridView/DetailsView to an UserControl and add this to the ContentTemplate of the TabPanel.

Here is a good tutorial on how to lazy-load TabPanels:
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html

Answer (score 0):

From the toolkit (just add tabpannels in your aspx page; the error will be solved):

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" 
    OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction" 
    Height="150px">
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" 
    HeaderText="Signature and Bio"
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
    </ContentTemplate>
/>
```

Comment: I already have tab panels in my aspx page though. I'll update my post to show how I add the panels.